# How to turn off a vim highlight group named //

Tags: vim

The two characters that introduce comments, namely //, get highlighted in yellow.  I don't want this.  It happens in files of all types: C, js, html, pl.

When I consult the vim help, it says to do this

```
 :so $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/hitest.vim
```

to see the highlight groups.  (I can also do this with :hi).

I do see a `//` highlight group.  The documentation reads to me as if I could do the following to turn the highlighting off

```
:hi // NONE
```

but it doesn't work for me.  (Gives me `Invalid character in group name`.)  Mac OS, vim version 8.0

Comment: I added an answer, but it's hard to know what's going on for certain without the output from `:hi` in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you *certain* that the highlight group in question you're after is named `//`?  I know that's not the name of the highlight group for JavaScript syntax.

You can [look at the highlight group definitions in the vim syntax files on Github](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/91f84f6e11cd879d43d651c0903d85bff95f0716/runtime/syntax/javascript.vim#L89):

```
" Define the default highlighting.
" Only when an item doesn't have highlighting yet
hi def link javaScriptComment       Comment
hi def link javaScriptLineComment       Comment
hi def link javaScriptCommentTodo       Todo
hi def link javaScriptSpecial       Special
hi def link javaScriptStringS       String
hi def link javaScriptStringD       String
hi def link javaScriptStringT       String
hi def link javaScriptCharacter     Character
```

So `:hi javaScriptComment NONE` should unhighlight just JavaScript comments.  And `:hi Comment NONE` would unhlighlight comments of all types.

Comment: To my great frustration, the highlights have disappeared, without me knowing how.  Thanks for your input.  If they come back, I'll try your :hi Comment NONE suggestion.